# Record visitor's IP in Database

Tags: php, html, database, tracking, uniqueidentifier

I want to implement something on my website to record the visitor's IP address and put it into a database with a unique id for support and analytics.
Does anyone know of a way to do that, with out changing my pages to PHP, or making the process  to crazy to do.

Thanks in advance, 
Peter 
I will use PHP if needed. Any answer is helpful

Comment: -1 for tracking visitors and recording IP addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can without having to change the page to a dynamic page, but in the end you need some dynamic web page or web service to write to a database. That dynamic page can be on another website even, but you can not write to a database or file from a static page (not even via javascript).

In your static page you can add two javascript functions:
First get the IP-address using pure Javascript. See: [How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)

Then make an ajax call (again from javascript) to a service you create and host somewhere else. Send the ip address to that service and log it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done without PHP, if you do decide to do it with PHP, then simply create a table with an `id` which is a `primary key` and which `auto_increment`, and an IP which is `varchar(15)` and `unique`

Then in your index, or whatever page you want to record it with, simply add this

```
$link = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `TABLE_NAME` (`ip`) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this without PHP.

Make a table named "iplogs" in your database with one field called "id", and define it as a auto-increment
Add another field to the table called "ip" as a text field.

php:

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost"; 
    $ip_user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] 

    //connect to database
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    //Select database
    $dbname = mysql_select_db($db_name, $dbhandle) or die("Cannot find the database");

    //execute the SQL INSERT query
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO iplogs (ip) VALUES (" . $ip_user . ")");

    //close the connection
    mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: Ok, what would you recommend for this with php

Comment: Do you use mySql for your database?